# SQL Server Data Tools for VS 2015 - Anyone using for SSIS development to multiple versions?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssdt, visual-studio

According to this link, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4253/backwards-compatibility-in-sql-server-data-tools-for-integration-services/ 
 the newest version of SQL Server Data Tools - "SSDT for Visual Studio 15" (16.5) is compatible with SQL 2016 AND older versions as well. In previous incarnations of the software, whether it was called "SQL Server Data Tools", "SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence", or "Business Intelligence Development Studio", we always seemed to run into version incompatibility issues when deploying.

If I'm reading this correctly, we could uninstall all older versions of the tools, and just install SSDT 16.5 for development of SSIS packages for SQL 2012 and newer. Due to many issues I've seen in past versions of the tools, I am hesitant to develop new projects in this.

**Is anyone successfully deploying SSIS packages to SQL 2016 AND older versions with SSDT 16.5?** Obviously, tasks that are only supported in newer versions wouldn't work in older versions.

Comment: I just recently installed SSDT 2015, and used it to create an SSIS package which I'm running on a couple of 2012 databases. It's not a terribly complicated package. I initially developed it on the default setting (2016), and had to change it to bring it down to 2012 (which didn't require any changes to the package as I'd developed it).

Comment: @SomeGuy i answered ur question whithout getting any reply!!

Comment: @RDFozz how did change the setting? I built my package in VS2015, it ran fine against a SQL2012 instance.  I deployed it to a SQL2012 instance and it failed with "package error: Package migration from version 8 to version 6."

Comment: @JamesJenkins - In VS2015, right-click the *project* (not the package or the solution), and select "Properties". In the dialog box that pops up, expand "Configuration Properties", and select "General". You can set the "Target Server Version" there.

Answer (score 4):

Visual studio 2015 SSDT work with SQL Server 2016 and has a backward compatibility to SQL server 2014 and 2012 only.

```
Target version of SQL Server    |   Development environment for SSIS packages
2016    |   SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015
2014    |   SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015 or SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013
2012    |   SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015 or SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012
2008    |   Business Intelligence Development Studio from SQL Server 2008
```

The following link contains very helpful informations:

**For SQL Server 2008 /R2 editions**

- [Integration Services versions Side by side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/installing-integration-services-versions-side-by-side)

You have to install `Microsoft Visual Studio 2008` to deploy package for SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2 by default. *(newer versions will not work correctly)*

There are a lot of links saying that newer versions of visual studio cannot deploy SSIS 2008 packages correctly:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451053/can-sql-server-data-tools-work-with-sql-server-2008-ssis
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bff5e145-1c63-4221-b2ba-009ea96a9e05/can-i-use-vs2012-to-create-and-deploy-ssis-for-sql2008r2?forum=sqlintegrationservices
- https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1560322-364-1.aspx

Comment: "But in theory, You can create SSIS 2008 package using Visual Studio 2012 or 2013." I don't believe that is correct. Backwards compatibility is new to SSDT in Visual Studio 2016. The link you provided in the next sentence explains this. I don't think @SomeGuy cares about SSIS 2008 also.

Comment: @GregGalloway you're right, but i am trying to give an unbiased answer

Comment: it's good to make the answer broadly applicable even to SSIS 2008. If you will remove the sentence I quoted I will upvote your answer.

Comment: @GregGalloway i updated my answer